# Is there a way to emulate a QGroupVBoxLayout?

Tags: qt, qt4, nokia, qwidget

I am using Qt designer and I know how to use a QVBoxLayout and QGroupBox but it seems there is no such thing as a QGroupVBoxLayout.  So I have to put a QVBoxLayout inside of a QGroupBox but if I modify the dimensions of one I have to do the same to the other.  Is there a way to make them change dimensions together directly from QT designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a `QGroupBox` to the form
2. Add widgets to the `QGroupBox` at positions where you would expected to be when the layout is applied (it doesn't have to be precise)
3. Select the `QGroupBox` and click the *"Lay Out Vertically"* toolbar button (the one with three blue vertical bars)